# Using complex data structure in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I'm making an interactive line chart and I'm having troubles capturing the data from a complex data structure

I passed an array of "paths" and it works:

```
 path = [[{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int}],
        [{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int}],
        [{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int}]]
```

but this is the data structure that I'm using:

```
data:[{
      id: 0, 
      image:[int values], 
      path:[{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int}], 
      pixel:[int values]
      },
      id: 1, 
      image:[int values], 
      path:[{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int},{x:int,y:int}], 
      pixel:[int values]
      }]
```

And I make a line chart with a standard valueline function:

```
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); })
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

 chart.selectAll(".line-group")
    .data(path)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "line-group")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", valueline)
```

I'd like to pass the entire data array to d3js and that the function "valueline", captures x and y from the "path" key of each image in the data array.

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 chart.selectAll(".line-group")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "line-group")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", d => valueline(d.path))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21955279)

Comment: @AashishJ: It is a solution to the question, Ricardo uses the same but in a strange non-D3 way

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using rioV8 solution.
I also found another workaround from https://amber.rbind.io/blog/2017/05/02/d3nest/:

```
chart.selectAll(".line-group")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "line-group")
    .selectAll(".lineChart")
    .data(function(d) { return [d.path] })
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "lineChart")
    .attr("d",valueline)
```